# How do I eliminate $x$ and $y$ from the system $x^2 y= a$, $x(x+y)= b$, $2x+y=c$ to get a single equation in $a$, $b$, $c$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Alright, a homework problem.

I'm stuck at this question,

> Eliminate $x$ and $y$ from the given equations to get a single
>   equation in terms of $a$ , $b$ and $c$
>
> $$\begin{align}
> x^2 y &= a \\
> x(x+y) &= b \\
> 2x+y &=c
> \end{align}$$

Let me tell you what I tried, I tried to get $y$ from one equation and substitute in the other two. Turns out that I'm not able to fully get rid of both $x$ and $y$. Help please.

Comment: can you show what you have obtained currently?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh yea sure, it's not anything impressive though. I was just trying things out to see where it goes.

Comment: Why not totally isolate $y$? $y=\frac a{x^2} = \frac bx-x=c-2x$ You can use this to get rid of $x$.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan yes that's exactly what I tried. But that's the thing, I'm not able to get rid of both. Either $x$ stays in or $y$.

Comment: Solve 2nd eqn for $y$, sub into 3rd eqn, solve that for $x$, etc.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm getting a quadratic with horrifying roots. $x= \dfrac{c±\sqrt{c^2-4b}}{2}$ Now what do I do with this monster? Sub in eq 1? But still $y$ will not get eliminated.

Comment: @greedoid nope it's $x(x+y)=b$ alright!

Comment: $a,b,c$ are real?

Comment: @greedoid that wasn't mentioned in the question, but I guess it would be okay even if it's not real.

Comment: Horrifying? I think it's absolutely gorgeous! Anyway, now you've got $x$, you can sub into any one of the three equations to get $y$.

Answer (score 5):

I'm confused why you say in comments that "still $y$ does not get eliminated" -- at a point in the conversation where $y$ should have disappeared long ago.

You can solve your third equation $2x+y=c$ to get $y=c-2x$. When you plug that into the two *other* equations you get
$$ x^2(c-2x)=a \\
x(x+c-2x)= b $$
No matter what you do subsequently, there won't be any $y$s left to deal with!

What I would do at this point is put off dividing for as long as possible, so rewrite the *second* equation to
$$ x^2 = cx - b $$
This form lets you reduce any polynomial in $x$ to a first-degree polynomial, by repeatedly using it to eliminate the highest-degree term. We will use it to simplify the third-degree *first* equation. First substitute the leading $x^2$ to get
$$ (cx-b)(c-2x) = a $$
Multiply out:
$$ c^2x + 2bx - 2cx^2 - bc = a $$
and then insert $x^2=cx-b$ once again:
$$ c^2x + 2bx - 2c(cx-b) - bc = a $$
This is finally a *linear* equation in $x$. You can solve it **without running into any square roots**, and insert this value for $x$ into $x^2=cx-b$. What is left then is a rational equation in only $a$, $b$, and $c$, as desired.

Unless the coefficient of $x$ in the linear equation was $0$ (which is a case you'll need to handle separately), each step along the way was reversible, so you will know that if you have $a,b,c$ that satisfy the final equation, they will also have a solution for $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Combine the first and second equations to eliminate $y$:

$x(x+\frac{a}{x^2})=b$

which tidies to

$x^2+\frac{a}{x}=b$ ....... (1)

combine the second and third equations to eliminate $y$:

$x(x+c-2x)=b$

which tidies to

$x^2-cx+b=0$

solving this quadratic gives

$x=\frac{c \pm \sqrt{c^2-4b}}{2}$

which you can substitute into equation (1):

$\left(\frac{c \pm \sqrt{c^2-4b}}{2}\right)^2+\frac{a}{\left(\frac{c \pm \sqrt{c^2-4b}}{2}\right)}=b$

Comment: It might be messy but it is, at least, an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can notice that the product resp. the sum of $x$ and $x+y$ are $c$ resp. $b$, you solve that and get a simple system in $x$ and $x+y$ and you substitute in the first equation.  Pretty same ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I will work with 2nd and 3rd equations to solve for $x$ and $y$.

From (3) we get,
$$y=c-2x$$
Substituting the value in (2) we get,
$$x(x+(c-2x))=b$$
$$\implies x^2-cx+b=0$$
$$x=\dfrac{1}{2}(c+\sqrt{c^2-4b}) \text{ or, }\dfrac{1}{2}(c+\sqrt{c^2-4b})$$
If $x=\dfrac{1}{2}(c+\sqrt{c^2-4b})$,then,
$$y=-\sqrt{c^2-4b}$$

Now,we plug the values of x and y in equation in (1),
We get,

$$-\dfrac{1}{4}(c^2+2c\sqrt{c^2-4b}+c^2-4b)\sqrt{c^2-4b}=a$$
**And this is the required equation.**

[If you use another value of $x$ then,we will get another equation like it.]